# Skip Login For a Particular Action of a Particular Controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I am using Devise and CanCan in my rails application. My problem is that I want to make a particular action (`basket_public_url`) for a particular controller (`BasketsController`) public. I know how to skip controllers for authorization. Is there a way around?

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization#conditionally-check-authorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to skip login, this means you want to bypass both authentication and authorization.

```
class BasketsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => :basket_public_url
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :basket_public_url

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CanCan 1.5 and higher, you can use `skip_authorize_resource` or `skip_load_and_authorize_resource`.

```
class BasketController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :basket_public_url
end
```

Reference link:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: Does not work, it is going into the ability file that it actually causing it to call user.admin method.. which raises an exception

Comment: Have you used authorize! method inside controller somewhere. Can you post code where you are doing authorization. What code you are using to authorize?